# How to prove that the given matrix is totally unimodular?

Tags: matrices, total-unimodularity

I need to prove that if we concatenate a vector of ones to the bottom and to the right of the identity matrix, the resulting matrix is totally unimodular.

For example, for $2\times2$ identity matrix we get the following matrix:

$$ \left [ \begin{matrix}
     \color{red}1 &  \color{red}0 & 1 \\
     \color{red}0 &  \color{red}1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$

And for $3\times3$ identity matrix we get:

$$ \left [ \begin{matrix}
     \color{red}1 &  \color{red}0 & \color{red}0  & 1 \\
     \color{red}0 &  \color{red}1 & \color{red}0 &  1 \\
     \color{red}0 &  \color{red}0 &\color{red}1 &  1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$

I don't know how to prove it, since each row and column contains more then two non-zero numbers, so I can't use the row/column partition method. I thought about using induction, but I am not sure how.

Comment: You can use standard method for the last column (1,1,1,...1). Each of sub matrix is of determinant 1 or -1. QED

Comment: @Markiff I don't know this method

Comment: https://www.hec.ca/en/cams/help/topics/Matrix_determinants.pdf